# Sorting issue: i have li and i want it to sort by clicking on Asc and Desc

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I want to sort list Ascending and Descending order.
When i click on Ascending it will sort on Ascending order same as Descending order,Sorting should be apply by using jQuery or any other javascript library.
Example code added on jsfiddle please click on link

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdgjus76/1/)

```
<p><a href="#" id="asc">Ascending</a> | <a href="#" id="desc">Descending</a></p>
<ul id="test">
<li style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid transparent;">

    <a href="/redlands/gourmet-pizza-shoppe" rel="962" class="to_business"><span>Gourmet Pizza Shoppe</span></a>
</li>
<li style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid transparent;">

    <a href="/redlands/therons-frozen-custard" rel="1020"
       class="to_business"><span>Theron's Frozen Custard</span></a>
</li>
<li style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid transparent;">

    <a href="/redlands/mu-restaurant-and-bar" rel="1024" class="to_business"><span>Mu Restaurant and Bar</span></a>
</li>
<li style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid transparent;">

    <a href="/redlands/redlands-underground" rel="1026" class="to_business"><span>Redlands Underground</span></a>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: Now it simple and easy to understand
i want to sort list  by text that is in span tag with in a tag

Comment: So where are you stuck? Apologies, you're clearly making an effort (shortening the markup and such so the question is nicely contained), but at present this reads a bit like "please write this sorting code for me." Take a stab at it, looking through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com), and if you get stuck post your effort and people will be happy to help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
$(function() {
$('#asc,#desc').click(function() {
    var $sort = this;
    var $list = $('#test');
    var $listLi = $('li',$list);
    $listLi.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = $(a).find('span').text();
        var keyB = $(b).find('span').text();
        if($($sort).is('#asc')){
            return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
            return (keyA < keyB) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
    $.each($listLi, function(index, row){
        $list.append(row);
    });
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdgjus76/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#asc, #desc').on('click', function() {

        var sortMethod = $(this).attr('id');
        var options = $('ul#test > li');

        options.sort(function(a, b){
            var aText = $(a).find('a span').text();
            var bText = $(b).find('a span').text();
            if(sortMethod == 'asc'){
                return aText.localeCompare(bText);
            }else{
                return bText.localeCompare(aText);
            }
        });

        $('ul#test').append(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: You could've added some explanations rather than posting only the code